# finding the indices of max values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with m rows and n columns.
I want to find the column index of max value appearing in each row.

I tried using idxmax, but it returns only the first occurrence of the max value.  The dataframe has more than one max value per row and I want to get all the indices of max values in every row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (3, 10)))

print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  3  0  0  2  2  4  0  2  1  2
1  3  4  0  4  4  1  1  0  2  3
2  4  1  3  4  4  4  0  3  1  0

res = [np.where(i == np.max(i)) for i in df.values]

print(res)

[array([5], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 3, 4], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)]
```